# Why is Jetpack Compose Material Modal designed as a nested component mode?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose in real situation, I need multiple modal components.

```kotlin
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = state.drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
      ModalDrawerSheet {
        ...
      }
    },
    content = {
      ModalNavigationDrawer(
         ...
       )
    }
  )
```

In this example I just use two `ModalNavigationDrawer`.

I'm confused, why should it be designed in such a nested form? Is there any reason to have to do this?

Why can't it be simpler like below?

```kotlin
ModalNavigationDrawer(...)
ModalNavigationDrawer(...)

...
```

Can you tell more information or sources on why did it?

Comment: "I need multiple modal components"... Why do you need a navigation drawer as the main content (the "content" parameter) of a screen that already has a navigation drawer? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @S.Gomez Generally, it is provided for user interaction and operation interface. I think your solution is to switch Content, but why is it designed like this?